# Uniqueness of nonlinear inhomogeneous system of ODE

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, integral-equations

Suppose for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$,
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=A(t,x(t))x(t)+\frac{dg}{dt}, \quad x(0)=0$$
has a solution that exists for all time where $A(t,x(t)),$ $\frac{dg}{dt}$ are continuous and bounded functions. I'd like to show the solution is unique. To this end, I integrate and have
$$x(t)=g(t)+\int_0^tA(\tau,x(\tau))x(\tau)d\tau.
$$
Define 
$$Tx=g(t)+\int_0^tA(\tau,x(\tau))x(\tau)d\tau
$$
and attempt to show $T$ is a contraction mapping.
$$\left|Tx-Ty\right|\leq\int\left|A(\tau,x(\tau))x(\tau)-A(\tau,y(\tau))y(\tau)\right|d\tau.$$
I'm stuck trying to estimate this quantity since $A(t,x(t))$ is not Lipschitz continuous. I've tried manipulating so I could use Gronwall's inequality among other basic estimates, but to no avail. Is there another strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It need not hold. It suffices to find a counter-example for a neighborhood of a point (easiest when different from the origin). Consider e.g. for $x$ in a neighborhood of $1$ the initial value problem:
 $$ \dot{x} = 2\sqrt{|\ln (x(t)) |}\;  x(t) , \; \; \; x(0)=1$$

Then $x(t)\equiv 1$ is a solution, but you may also take $x(t)=1, t<0$ and for
$0\leq t \leq \delta$:  $$ x(t) = e^{t^2} ,$$
since for $t\geq 0$:
  $$ \dot{x} = 2 t \;e^{t^2} = 2 \sqrt{\ln x(t)} \; \; x(t) $$
You may modify this example to a global one in ${\Bbb R}$ verifying the stated conditions. You need a suitable $g$ that takes you from an initial position at the origin (at the origin the solution is unique) to a non-zero $x$ value, say $x=1$, and then employ my counter-example in the vicinity of that value.